# how to minimalized methods body from default in eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I want all methods in my project to be "minimalized" from default.
(now I can do this when I "click" minus button).

Is there any setting in Eclipse Juno which let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the folding preferences so that all your methods are minimized when you open the editor.

Go to `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding`.

Under "Initially fold these elements", check the Option `Members`:

[image]